# deleteing a node cypher java

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

i'm working with neo4j version 2.2.1. I would like to know how to delete a specific node using a cypher query in a java program containing a parameter.
i tried this but it wouldn't work :

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("numero", "1");
String query1 ="MATCH (pe:Person) WHERE PeNumero={numero} DELETE pe";
Result result1 = graphDb.execute( query1, params);
```

Person is my node label, and PeNumero is one of its properties.
Thanks a lot, ghrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem is finally solved. I used a Cypher query to find the node, retrieve its id and then delete the node using a transaction that gets the node by id.It worked !
Thanks FrobberOfBits and cybersam.

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete a node, you'll probably have to delete its relationships too.  Otherwise deleting a node would leave "dangling" relationships, which wouldn't mean anything and that's not permitted.   Try this instead:

```
MATCH (pe:Person)-[r]-(m) WHERE PeNumero={numero} DELETE r, pe;
```

Comment: I just tried it, i got an error about PeNumero not being defined. i tried 
MATCH (pe:Person)-[r]-(m) WHERE pe.PeNumero={numero} DELETE r, pe;
No errors but still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the node actually exist? That is, does this query return a node: `MATCH (pe:Person) WHERE pe.PeNumero={numero}  RETURN pe`?

Comment: Yes that query returns a node. I have  created nodes. But I don't know how to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
MATCH (pe:Person {PeNumero:{numero}})
OPTIONAL MATCH (pe)-[r]-(m) 
DELETE r, pe;
```

It will delete that particular node and if that node having some relationships, then that relationships will get deleted.

You can check references here http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-delete.html

Comment: Hello  Satish, i just tried that query, i got an error    :  "Invalid input 'O': expected whitespace, comment, ')' or a relationship pattern"
i'm working with Cypher embedded in Java. The solution i just put that uses transactions worked (not the best one but it solves the deal ) 
Thank you !